# How can i convert a .bin file to a .json file

Tags: binary-files, json, file-conversion

There is a ".bin" file on my pc that i want to convert. I tried to do it with a ISO reader but it wont work. The only thing i know about this file, it stores some json data that i want to see.

Im not sure if this is useful but the insides of the files looks like this:

`^@b^@^B^B...` and so on.

Also there is a json file that has this text inside, this may be useful too.

```
{ "Binary" : 2636390306 }
```

Note: I know it is a json file because a guy already parsed some info about this file but im not sure how he did it. He sent an image inside an text editor with this content:

```
file_name.bin_struct.txt


00-01 = example value 1
02-03 = example value 2
9B-0C = example value 3
```

etc, you get the idea.

Im wondering if there is any program to convert this file bin to json or just the method name this guy used to get the data about the file

Comment: This depends entirely on what is inside the bin file. So, what is inside the bin file? What have you done to open it? We do not entertain software recommendations requests here. Please read the help section to better understand this site and how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a ".bin" file on my pc that i want to convert. I tried to do it with a ISO reader but it wont work. The only thing i know about this file, it stores some json data that i want to see.

Are you sure it's storing JSON-formatted data? If it were, then you'd be able to read it with a text editor. The whole idea of binary data is that the underlying structure is left out of what's written. Instead, you have to know which bytes correspond to which bits of data (the metadata/**schema**) when reading the binary data later. A program might know this schema and then translate it into JSON, but I suspect the file does not house JSON itself.

> Note: I know it is a json file because a guy already parsed some info about this file but im not sure how he did it. He sent an image inside an text editor with this content:
>
> ```
> file_name.bin_struct.txt
>
>
> 00-01 = example value 1
> 02-03 = example value 2
> 9B-0C = example value 3
> ```

Those look like addresses corresponding to bytes of data. First two bytes example 1, next two bytes example 2, skip many bytes to address `9B` and then... rotate back to `0C`? Maybe it's actually `AC`? In any case, there's more than two bytes for example 3.

This person you've referenced might be reverse-engineering the binary data, making educated guesses about which bytes are what. Or they might have the schema already and a program that uses the schema and spits out JSON from the bin file.

But regardless, if it's just binary data following an unknown metadata/schema, then no, there's no ready-made program to translate unknown binary data into a more meaningful format. At best, you could use something like the GNU/Linux `file` command to check if it happens to be a common binary format, or the `strings` command to peek around for human-readable data. After that, you've gotta break out the hex editor and start making educated guesses yourself. And before you know it, you can be a reverse engineer too :)

Comment: 1- Yes this stores formatted json data about items for a game (id, damage, etc)

like this: (example)

`
{
    "id": 154
    "weapon_damage": 100
    "weapon_reach": 0.30
}
`

2- i skipped some values on that example but it goes from 00-01, 02-03 and so on. like as you said, he is guessing the data.

Note: when i ment "insides of the file", i opened the .bin file that looks like that ( ^@b^@^B^B, etc )

also, thanks for the reply, that linux files command may be useful for what im trying to do.